# Is there an efficient way of calculating the density of 1s in bitstream?

Tags: algorithm

I am attempting to come up with a good method of comparing binary arrays (from length 1 to length 1000) to determine a relative 'density' of 1's.

01010101 would be less dense than 00011011, as the 1's are more spread out.

Likewise, the total number is important. Thus, 11111111 is worse (higher value) than 11, despite both being 100% 1's. (Padding the second to 00000011 would solve this issue, but cause later problems).

The algorithm will be used in nested loops (scoring method in genetic program), so my current solution of O(n^2) time and O(n) space will not cut it!

The two dirty methods I have so far will be explained using the following data (from a terrible algorithm that would be culled in gen 1):

```
Stream      Result A   Result B (8+7+6+5+4+3+2)
A: 001000       1.17          7  1+1+1+1+1+1+1
B: 000          0.00          0  0+0+0+0+0+0+0
C: 1011011      5.57         25  5+5+4+4+3+2+2
D: 1011         4.25         19  3+3+3+3+3+2+2
E: 1            2.00          7  1+1+1+1+1+1+1
F: 1001010      2.29         16  3+3+3+2+2+2+1
G: 11111111    16.00         35  8+7+6+5+4+3+2
H: 1001001      2.29         14  3+3+2+2+2+1+1
I: 10101        2.80         17  3+3+3+3+2+2+1
```

**Result A:** The calculation is the number of 1's squared, divided by the total number of digits, plus the max size of contiguous 1's. So for **C**, 5 out of 7 are 1's, with the max grouping of 2, so 2+(5*5/7). The problem with this method is that **F** and **H** are matching, despite **F** being more 'bunched up'. The benefit is that it runs in O(n), and has space of O(1) [4 variables: num1s, totalnum, maxBunch, bunchSoFar] by keeping a running total.

**Result B:** The calculation is to start with n = maximum size (in this case 8, but in my program 900), and count the maximum number of 1's that can be captured by grouping n consecutive digits together. Then adding that to the max captured by grouping n-1 consecutive digits together. I stop at groupings of 2, because a grouping of 1 will always return 1 for any non-zero array. This has the benefit of correctly setting **H** as a lower score than **F**, but would require time O(n^2) and space O(n) as the entire array needs to be stored as more digits are being added. (Compression could help the space, but would be outweighed by the time cost).

**Conclusion**
I am looking for a more efficient method than Result B, yet can provide more detailed ordering than Result A. I attempted to google, but 'bit density' refers to something completely different! I will keep working on this, but thought that, in parallel, I would ask to see if anyone happens to know of an algorithm already that I don't know the name of.

Comment: Your problem here is way too underspecified. There's simply too many approaches to measuring something this vague. Try asking about what you're *trying to accomplish*, not how to *implement the approach you've decided on*. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: If by *n* in O(n), you mean the length of a single string, then your second approach can also be implemented in O(n). Just put two pointers and move the second one as long as the 1-bit sequence is ongoing. Then store the length to a map. As to how exactly you should compute density, it really depends on what you expect from it as the other commenter has explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in python3, the approach is that on reading a 0 subtract from the final value and on reading a 1 add to the final value. To take into account the closeness of 1s and 0s, for every consecutive 0 you subtract a larger number and for every consecutive 1 you add a larger number. For example for a 5 bit number:

00011 will compute -1, -2, -3, +1 and +2

while

00101 will compute -1. -2, +1, -1 and +1

Instead of padding with 0s, remove leading 0s using `str = str.lstrip("0")`

Initialise sum as `sum = 8 - len(bits)` (in your case `sum = 900 - len(bits)`).

Then `sum = -((sum * (sum + 1)) / 2)`

Then you can traverse in O(n) and extra space used is O(1) using the following for loop:

```
    prev = 0
    prev_a = '0'
    for x in str:
        if x == '0':
            prev -= 1
            if prev_a == '0':
                sum += prev
            else:
                sum += -1
                prev = -1
            prev_a = '0'
        else:
            prev += 1
            if prev_a == '1':
                sum += prev
            else:
                sum += 1
                prev = 1
            prev_a = '1'
    print(str, sum)
```

This gives the output as:

```
10000000 :   -27.0
001000 :     -15.0
000 :        -36.0
1011011 :    4.0
1011 :       -7.0
1 :          -27.0
1001010 :    -3.0
11111111 :   36.0
1001001 :    -4.0
10101 :      -5.0
```

You can add 36 to the sum at the end to get all positive values.

Higher number indicating better Density of 1s.